# How do I use a Wacom Intuos 2 on OS X Sierra?

Tags: macos, software, wacom

I have a Wacom Intuos 2 and a 2009 MacBook running OS X Sierra (not High Sierra). Is there any way I can possibly get the tablet to work with my computer?

Comment: The Bamboo is different line than the Intuos - so this Q&A might be totally irrelevant, but I wanted to draw attention in case it helps get you a driver or a procedure. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/252307/wacom-bamboo-create-driver-for-macos-10-12 (and [same with the spire tablet](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/210735/is-it-possible-to-use-old-wacom-tablet-on-10-11) )

Comment: Re: duplicate question - specifically this answer was the way that worked for me with an Intuos 2 - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/312711/85275

Answer (score 1):

From here, [Is it possible to use old Wacom tablet on 10.11?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/210735/is-it-possible-to-use-old-wacom-tablet-on-10-11)

Drivers (look down page): https://www.wacom.com/en-us/support/product-support/drivers

How worked for me. Sierra 10.12.6 Intuos GD-0608-U. Clean installation driver 6.2.0w4 Go /Library/PreferencePanes, move to desktop WacomTablet.prefpane, open package (I use Pacifist on demo) and extract Info.plist, trash this WacomTablet.prefpane From driver 6.3.15-3, open installer package (Pacifist again) DO NOT INSTALL, open package, copy to desktop WacomTablet.prefpane, open package, change the Info.plist (with the one from 6.2.0w4). Close all. Put this prefpane in /Library/PreferencePanes. I set System Preferences.app to 32bit with info, before open Preferences, is working, close and set off 32bit. Summary: Is a 6.2.0w4 installation with a preferences panel from 6.3.15-3 which has inside an Info.plist from 6.2.0w4. This works so did not try any other version of the driver.
NOTE: whats different for me, is that all information is about a newest driver with and oldest PrefPane, that did not worked for me. The last driver for Intuos (GD series) is 6.2.0w4 and did not work on osX 10.12.6, so use that oldest driver installation, but with a newest PrefPane from 6.3.15-3 with inside the info.plist from 6.2.0w4. And you get a full functional System Preferences Panel, don't need old preferences file.

Comment: Hello. Had to do a MacOS reinstall and went all the way to 10.13.6 without installing first the wacom's driver. Bad idea, from 10.13.5 and 10.13.6 there is no way to change applications to 32-bits, so can not do the trick.
Lazy to go down Mac OS version to install driver, looking for a fast solution found this:
https://github.com/thenickdude/wacom-driver-fix
Tested his full driver install, works great for me. Tranks a lot.